# Poker Combinations: How many 5-cards poker hands are there containing at least 2 of the 4 suits?

Tags: combinatorics

Not sure where to start. Do I start with choosing 5 cards from 52? Then pick 5 from 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many $5$-card poker hands are there containing all cards from the same suit? If we find the answer to that, then we know how many hands you *don't* want to count.

There are $4$ ways to pick the suit, then we pick the $5$ cards from the $13$ of the suit. Finally we subtract this number from the total number of $5$-card poker hands:

$$\binom{52}{5}-4\binom{13}{5}$$

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Yes you can count the number of hands with exactly 2 suits, then the number with exactly 3 suits, then the number with all four suits, then add them up. I think the way in this answer is much faster/easier.

Comment: I agree this is by far the easiest approach.

Comment: How would the answer deviate if the question said at least 3 of the 4 suits?

Comment: Then the complementary counting method would take about as long as counting directly

Answer (score 0):

Would this be incorrect?

1. Pick 2 of the 4 suits, then there 13 ways to pick each card so 13^2
2. Now for the remaining 3 cards, C(50,3)

19874400 ways

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect.  This is greater than the $2,598,960$ total poker hands.  You have counted every acceptable hand many times.  For example, AS, 2S, 3S, 4S, AH is counted by picking AS and AH first and 234S second and also as 2S, AH first and A34S second.

Comment: You have to be very careful not to double count if you want to follow this approach.  Following on @Zubin Mukerjee's comment, to get the ones with exactly two suits you can say six ways to choose the two suits where the first suit chosen will supply more cards than the second.  Then given the two suits there are ${13 \choose 4}{13 \choose 1}+{13 \choose 3}{13 \choose 2}$ ways to select the particular cards, for a total of $546,546$ such hands.  You still need to count the hands with three or four suits represented.